OpenCL : high fix cost to run gpu instructions, what to do?
I'm using OpenCL in c++. My GPU is NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3070.
I have a very simple kernel
__kernel void op_exp_f(global float* vOut)
{
    const uint i = get_global_id(0);
    vOut[i] = exp(vOut[i]);
}

I build my kernel, allocate GPU memory (with clCreateBuffer CL_MEM_READ_WRITE) and run the following method
inline void op_exp(cl_mem buffer, size_t n)
{
    auto& instance = gpuInstance();
    auto& kernel = instance._kernel_op_exp;
    clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &buffer));
    auto queue = instance.GetCommandQueue();
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(queue, kernel, 1, NULL, &n, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    clFinish(queue);
}

I measured the time to run op_exp.
When the size is between 1 and 130,000 the execution time is roughly constant at 20µs.
I find it pretty high knowing that this time doesn't include building the kernel, allocating memory or transferring memory.
When the size goes from 130,000 to 16,000,000 I see that the time is linear.
What can I do to reduce this 20µs fix cost ?
(Question edited, I wrote initially that the fix cost was 20ms instead of 20 µs)

Launching kernels and waiting for their results is an expensive operation, you need to make sure that your kernel is doing enough work to make it worth the effort

20ms is typical ?

Why do you think that does not include memory transfer time?

20ms is extremely high though. For few hundreds kb. Network transfer is faster.

are you using a debug or release build? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45078951/slow-gpu-performance-on-opencl-kernel

@AlanBirtles release!

so sorry, i made a mistake my timing is  20µs not 20ms.
it sounds more reasonable, right ?
